# Virtual service callbacks

Tags: ros, rosservice, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Community,
This might seem a strange question. Is it possible to declare a service callback as virtual? Or more importantly can I override the service callback with another function if required?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44365/virtual-service-callbacks/) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/bind/bind.html) to binds methods and use them as callbacks.

Callbacks can be changed at runtime (the API usually allows it but in the worst case you can destroy and recreate a publisher/subscriber) so it is not necessary to use complex dispatch methods. Of course, if it benefits code readability, using virtual methods is good too :)

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1